# Find how many out-of-bag records were there in a Random forest model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

My oob_score is 0.97 and the accuracy on test data is 0.97.
Is there a way to know how many samples is being used to calculate oob_score ?

This may give some more confidence on results.

```
rf.oob_score_ # for oob score

rf.score(X_test_scaled,y_test) # for accuracy on test data
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be ca. 36% of your sample: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228451484
I'm not sure about calculating the exact number (especially sense the number of oob samples really only pertains to the bootstrapped sample they belong to), but another post goes into further detail on where this 36-37% estimate really comes from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173520/random-forests-out-of-bag-sample-size